# Delete files containing "some text" in folder with many files (100k+)

Tags: grep, find, exec, rm

I'm trying to delete session files our system has created for search bots. What worked last time doesn't work this time, I guess because the number of session files has increased.

I was using `grep -l 'spider' * | xargs rm`

But now I'm getting an `Argument list too long` error from `grep`.

Is there some way I can use `find` with `grep` and `rm` to accomplish this?

EDIT:

None of the files have spaces in them.

I was thinking that, since `grep` can't handle the number of files, I might use `find` just to manage the huge number of files because I thought (perhaps incorrectly) that `find` with `exec` and `{}` would automatically break the files into manageable chunks. But maybe that won't work.

One way or another, though, I really need to remove these files!

EDIT:

I was not able to solve this, really. I deleted older files until the file count was small enough that I could run this:

```
grep -l "spider" * | xargs rm
```

Then I set up a cron to run the command every few minutes. I am now able to make the session lifetimes longer because the frequency of the cron means fewer files to run the `rm` command against.

Comment: Isn't it rm that's complaining about the number of arguments?

Comment: is there any common file name pattern with the files you are deleting?  Is there any way you can avoid looking at the contents of each file?

Comment: @aguibert there is no pattern right now. The file names are session hashes. There's no way to tell a human session hash from a bot one. But perhaps in the future I could alter the session-creation code and specially name the bot session files.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the amount of arguments xargs passes to its command with `-n N` where `N` is the number of arguments.

You could try different values of N.

```
xargs -n 500 rm
```

You could also see if the following works on your system to determine limits.

```
xargs --show-limits
```

If you need to look into the filename with grep, you could chain the commands

```
find . -type f | xargs -n 500 grep -l "spider" | xargs -n 500 ...
```

Another way to delete files avoiding command line limits (though, will not work in this case, as the filter is within the file, not filename).

```
find * -name "some file name pattern" -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: I tried `-n 50000` and `-n 5000` and still grep is complaining. I'm pretty sure it handled far more than 5000 last time.

Comment: Also note your `find` won't work since it's looking for filenames. I need to delete files containing the text "spider".

Comment: the `find` command does something else. it checks the file name, not the file content.

Comment: @Kent Yes and I need to delete files containing the word "spider", regardless of their names.

Comment: @JRD are you suggesting I grep 500 files at a time until I've gone through all 109,000? Seems like a lot of typing.

Comment: Well you have a limit on how many you can do at a time, so you have to pick some number that fits under the limit. 500 is just an arbitrary number used for example. Not sure what you mean by a lot of typing. The command written on the command line is the same whether the number is 1, 500, 5000 or any number.

Comment: @JRD well if I use `find . -type f | xargs -n 500 grep -l "spider" | xargs -n 500 grep -l "spider" ...` won't I end up typing the `xargs -n 500 grep -l "spider" ` thing about 200 times, right?

Comment: No, you only need to run that command once. `find` will find all the files (100k) and pass that list to grep 500 files at a time until the full list is exhausted, likewise passing the matched files from grep to rm 500 at a time. The 500 number you can adjust to what makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

another idea is to build `rm xxx` statements and pipe to `sh`.

```
grep -l 'spider' * |sed 's/^/rm /'|sh
```

you can first remove the `|sh` to check if commands are ok. also if you have spaces in filename, you may want quote the names, by extending the `sed` a bit.

Comment: This still doesn't work. The basis of the problem is that grep is overburdened by the `*`. `-bash: /bin/grep: Argument list too long`